# An env variable is causing apt to 'Could not resolve'

Tags: networking, apt

Whenever I try to update/upgrade/install packages it tells me the following.

```
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease

Err http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease

Err http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'archive.canonical.com'
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease

Err http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease

Err http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease

Err http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'nl.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'nl.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'nl.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'archive.canonical.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'nl.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'nl.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'nl.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Whenever I check if I can resolve these hosts, the machine does just fine. e.g:

```
root@ubuntu-server:/etc# host  nl.archive.ubuntu.com
nl.archive.ubuntu.com is an alias for ubuntuarchive.bit.nl.
ubuntuarchive.bit.nl is an alias for ftp.bit.nl.
ftp.bit.nl has address 213.136.12.213
ftp.bit.nl has IPv6 address 2001:7b8:3:37::21:3
```

The machine has a working internet connection and there's nothing wrong with my resolv.conf

```
root@ubuntu-server:/etc# cat resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Any ideas whats wrong and what I can do to fix this?

EDIT: terminal environment variables:

```
root@ubuntu-server:/etc# printenv
XDG_SESSION_ID=6
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
SSH_CLIENT=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 2764 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
USER=root
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00        ;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga        =00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
MAIL=/var/mail/root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/us        r/local/games
PWD=/etc
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
SSH_CONNECTION=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 2764 192.168.1.15 22
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
_=/usr/bin/printenv
OLDPWD=/etc/network
```

Comment: check for any proxy settings in your terminal environment variables

Comment: Added them, got no idea what they are though

Comment: try `env -i apt-get update` to be sure no environment variables are impacting this

Comment: Aparently they are, working now. Any idea what env vars are causing this?

Comment: *no idea.*  let us know if you clear them one at a time to figure it out.  you can test each variable like: `XDG_SESSION_ID= apt-get update` (notice the space after the =).

Comment: maybe PATH. it looks like `/usr/local/games` has extra characters in it.

Comment: the path was my mistake

Comment: I will presume you have a proxy somewhere. Could you give the output of `apt-get -o Debug::Acquire::http=true update`. And the content of all files with `cat /etc/apt/apt.conf{,.d/*}`.

Answer (score 0):

It's highly unlikely that the listed environment variables could affect `apt-get`. However, the output of `host` is **not** a reliable indicator of whether hostname resolution is working.

Consider:

```
$ grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts:          files
$ host google.com
google.com has address 172.217.26.14
google.com has IPv6 address 2404:6800:4004:809::200e
google.com mail is handled by 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
$ sudo apt update
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not resolve 'jp.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'jp.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Could not resolve 'jp.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not resolve 'archive.canonical.com'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
12 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Failed to fetch http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve 'jp.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'jp.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'jp.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve 'archive.canonical.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

`apt-get`, and most applications, use glibc's [`gethostbyname(3)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/gethostbyname.3) for hostname resolution, which defers to `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to decide which methods to use for that. If `nsswitch.conf` is incorrectly configured, `host` (and `nslookup`, `dig`, etc.) will work fine, but most applications will fail in hostname resolution.

That is one possible cause.